# Can't locate SDK - VSC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, sdk

My initial error, in fact, comes from Unity that when I open a script (C#) from it to Visual Studio Code, it opens the code without "auto-completing" my lines of code, which makes learning more difficult.

To solve this problem, I used several tutorials, but none helped. That's why I decided to solve another problem that always appears when I open the Microsoft App, which is "The .NET Core SDK cannot be located: A valid dotnet installation could not be found.".

I installed the dotnet 6.0.44 version on my linux (zorin os 16.2) from commands on the official website and the OS identified it. However, no matter what I do, Visual Studio does not recognize it, not even in the terminal does it find it .

[command contradiction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QyX9.png)

[Dotnet version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37yro.png)

obs:

1. Already re-installed SDK

Comment: maybe stupid question, but since you didn't specify, have you tried restarting/reloading VS Code after changing your `PATH` variable?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error on Zorin OS and other Ubuntu based distributions,
you have to install the SDK by this command:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

If this gives you any errors, read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu).
You can view your installed SDKs by executing

```bash
$ dotnet --list-skds
```